# elementary OS Freya interface is broken after upgrade

Tags: system

Today I updated my system with

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After a restart wingpanel is displayed not correctly, it is missing transparency and I can drag it around. Slingshot now has a black border.
Guest session don't have this problems...
What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: have you tried this `sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-desktop`

Comment: Yes, no result. Also tried new user accont and its ok before reboot.

Comment: Propably a theme issue. Try with the default theme.